# How to integrate firebase authentication with instagram login for android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, instagram, instagram-api

I have integrated Facebook login and Twitter login as guided by the firebase tutorials. I am trying to integrate Instagram login for firebase authentication in my android application. I found [this firebase article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html). I have few problems with this guidance.

In Twitter and Facebook integration, firebase provided a callback URL.

Can't we get a custom redirect-uri from Firebase just like for facebook and twitter which will handle the redirection in the same way?

It seems according to [this guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html), we should have an authentication server endpoint to be redirected after Instagram authentication. In that case how to continue with the authentication process without any kind of interruption in the Android application? To put it another way what is the server side implementation of the redirect-uri endpoint?

Comment: Did you find an answer? Same problem here

Comment: Still not. it will be awesome if we can find an answer. I skipped that part of the app. This is a dying need.

Comment: Now you have an sample function to make instagram+firebase Auth .
Here is the github link to it:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth Read the readme provided to understand how to use .
Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Firebase Function. You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth). This is the fastest way to achieve Instagram login without having any server-side code.

However, you still need to upgrade to the **Blaze** plan from Firebase.

Comment: The Github rep does not exist anymore.